# Add subItem to Listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, subitem

Now, I know how to add SubItems, but this time it's slightly different from my usual method. below is what I'm using to add items to my listview, however using this I cannot figure out how to add subitems.

```
listView1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(f));
```

Comment: Path.GetFileName() returns a string.  Does listView1.Items hold string values?  I would think it holds some sort of listitem object

Comment: Do you want to get list of filename inside a directory and put them into listview items?

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath Well no, `ListView.ListViewItemCollection` does have an add method for strings https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttzhk9y3(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
listView1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(f));

listView1.Items[0 /* or any index you need */].SubItems.Add("SubItem");
```

Comment: I found this within the documentation a moment ago. This works for my purposes. thank you!